# Determine status of outer accordion regardless of the state of inner accordion

Tags: jquery, css

I have a website that has an accordion with multiple accordions inside it. I was trying to determine the state(expanded/collapsed) of the outer accordion by using the `$('#outer_accordion').hasClass('ui-state-active')` method to check.

However, this method returns true when inner accordion are expanded but the outer accordion are collapsed.

Is there any way to know if the outer accordion is expanded or collapsed regardless of the state of the inner accordion?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Dude, did you try to close inner accordions first? and only expand the outer one and try this code?

Comment: It will work if inner accordions are closed. However, is it possible to have a true value if inner accordions are opened but the outer accordion is closed?

Comment: Can u make a Js fiddle or plunkr

Answer (score 1):

Maybe getting the state of the according "active" or not (false means collapsed - according to the documentation) may help you:
http://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/accordion/#option-active

in your case you can do:

```
// Getter
var active = $( "#outer_accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
```